# Backbone: Fetched data from server not displaying on view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and I just can't seem to display the data from a collection. Please point out the incorrect part.

Consider these js codes:

```
App.ProvidersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: "Providers",

    template: "#-providers-template",

    render: function() {
        var html = $(this.template).tmpl();
        $(this.el).html(html).addClass('container-fluid');
        this.collection.each(this.renderProvider);
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "renderProvider");
    },

    renderProvider: function(Provider){
        var ProviderView = new App.ProviderView({
            model: Provider
        });
        ProviderView.render(Provider);
        $(this.el).append(ProviderView.el);
    }
});

App.ProviderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: "Provider",

    template: "#-provider-template",

    initialize: function(){
        this.template = $(this.template);
    },

    render: function(){
        var html = this.template.tmpl(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(html);
    }

});

App.Provider = Backbone.Model.extend();

App.ProviderCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "php/Provider.php",

    model: App.Provider
});

App.addInitializer(function() {

    var providers = new App.ProviderCollection();

    providers.fetch({success: function() {
        console.log(Providers.models);
    }});

    var provider = new App.Provider();

    var providersView = new App.ProvidersView({
        model: Provider,
        collection: Providers
    });

    providersView.render();

    $("#main").html(providersView.el);
    $("#providers-list").html(provider.el);

});

App.bind('initialize:after', function() {
    Backbone.history.start();
});

$(function() {
    App.start();
});
```

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="content-providers-template">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <h5>Content Providers</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content-providers-list"></div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="content-provider-template">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="panel">
                <h2 class="toggle"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-white pull-right"></i>${name}</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Dependencies:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
```

Also, if you can share really good resources to learning backbone, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you settings your view's `el` anywhere? `id` (at least in vanilla backbone.js, not sure about marionette) is a property of the models, not views.

Comment: Sorry, not sure. But the code works fine when you hardcode the json data and pass it to the collection instance. My problem is how to display the data from the server via collection fetch. It's not working.

Comment: Are you getting data back from the server? One potential *gotcha* to keep in mind is that fetch is asynchronous so it's possible that your render method is firing before the data is fetched.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually getting data. It can be determined using this:    
    console.log(providers.models);

Comment: Perhaps try calling the render method in your success callback (you can pass in the collection to your view before calling fetch).

Comment: Thanks. I tried, the view rendered but still no data.

    `providers.fetch({success: function() {
        console.log(providers.models);
        providersView.render();
    }});`

Comment: Are you sure `{name}` resolves to a property of your `Provider` model? If the object's data isn't converted via `toJson`, I wouldn't expect your property reference to work. I'm not sure which template engine you're using, but with underscore's templates, they're easy enough to debug. http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1837

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this to work after some time.

The point is that `fetch()` is asynchronous, meaning it returns before data from the server is loaded.

Here's the fix:

```
App.addInitializer(function() {

    var providers = new App.ProviderCollection();
    var provider = new App.Provider();

    var providersView = new App.ProvidersView({
        model: Provider,
        collection: Providers
    });

    providers.fetch({success: function() {
        console.log(Providers.models);
        providersView.render(); // Render after loading
    }});

    $("#main").html(providersView.el);
    $("#providers-list").html(provider.el);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
render: function() {
    var html = $(this.template).tmpl();
    $(this.el).html(html).addClass('container-fluid');
    var that = this;
    this.collection.each(function() {
        that.renderProvider();
    });
}
```

I guess, in your renderProvider method, You are getting wrong context of this.
This should work !!