# Model view shows only default values

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

what's wrong with my backbone.js code?
When a product page is loading only model's default values are displayed...
Although in a console I see correct data...
Here is my model:

```
var app = app || {};
app.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        coverImage: 'img/placeholder.png',
        id: null,
        name: 'Unknown',
        price: '100'
    }
});
```

Collection:

```
var app = app || {};
app.ProductList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Product,
    url: 'php/listProducts.php'
});
```

There is my view:

```
var app = app || {};
app.ProductItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#productPage').html()), 

    initialize: function(options) {
        var id = options.id;
        this.model = new app.Product();
        this.collection = new app.ProductList();
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(collection){
                console.log(collection.toJSON());
                console.log('Collection models: ', collection.models[id-1]);
                this.model = collection.models[id-1];
                console.log('This model: ', this.model);
            }
        });

        this.render();
    },

    render: function () { 
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );
        return this; 
    }


});
```

Router:

```
var app = app || {};
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "product/:id": "productPageShow"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.$content = $("#product-list");
    },

    productPageShow: function(id) {
        app.prodItView = new app.ProductItemView({ id: id });
        this.$content.html(app.prodItView.el);
    }

});

$(function() {
    new app.Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

My template:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div id="product-list"></div>
</div>

<script id="productPage" type="text/template">
    <div>
        <img src="<%= coverImage %>" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="<%= name %>">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2><%= name %></h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><%= price %></h3>
    </div>
</script>
```

Console image:

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI6FW.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone: Fetched data from server not displaying on view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330013/backbone-fetched-data-from-server-not-displaying-on-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because 'fetch' is an asynchronous action, so `render()` will always be called before the `success()`callback of the `fetch()` call.

Some extra resources if you want:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch

To explain visually on your code the order of execution in the `initialize` method:

```
var app = app || {};
app.ProductItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#productPage').html()), 

    initialize: function(options) {
        // 1
        var id = options.id;
        // 2
        this.model = new app.Product();
        // 3
        this.collection = new app.ProductList();
        // 4 - fetch is only called and ajax request is sent to your backend.
        //     success callback is still not called
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function(collection) {
                // 6 - when you get the data from the server the callback is called
                //     but the page is already rendered at this time
                console.log(collection.toJSON());
                console.log('Collection models: ', collection.models[id-1]);
                this.model = collection.models[id-1];
                console.log('This model: ', this.model);
            }
        });

        // 5
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () { 
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );
        return this; 
    }
});
```

The fix should be fairly trivial, just call the render method at the bottom of your success callback and bind to the correct context of the view:

```
var app = app || {};
app.ProductItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($('#productPage').html()), 

    initialize: function(options) {
        var id = options.id;
        this.model = new app.Product();
        this.collection = new app.ProductList();
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: _.bind(function(collection) {
                console.log(collection.toJSON());
                console.log('Collection models: ', collection.models[id-1]);
                this.model = collection.models[id-1];
                console.log('This model: ', this.model);

                // Moved render call here
                this.render();
            }, this)
        });

    },

    render: function () { 
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );
        return this; 
    }
});
```

Also, just as a general advice .. never pick models from a collection directly .. use the provided `get` method on a collection and pass the model `id` that you need .. use `collection.get(mnodelId)` over `collection.models[arrayIndexOfTheModel]`

Comment: Mario thanks a lot for your answer and advice! It works!

Comment: The `.fetch` function can take a `context` option which avoids using `_.bind`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron - this is indeed true. In all my years of working with Backbone I haven't noticed that. It's not in the docs, I only now confirmed it in the source code. It's strange though since `context` is usually passed as the last parameter, none the less, great tip! Thanks :)